# pandas: expanding mean based on conditions & excluding current row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Need to calculate each participating team's average goals per game (`rolling_avg`) up to a point in time. Since my database is highly normalized, this takes quite a lot of time (+8k rows)

**Notes:**

- I'm counting the total goals (column 0) scored in a match, not each team's goals.
- There are additional columns that are omitted here but could be relevant: one of them is a `date_time` column.

Example: in row #1 (the second row) we can see the first game of team `1249` (they're playing away). In this game, 3 goals were recorded. The next game of team `1249` takes place in row #10, and since that team is playing at home this time (as its `id` appears under `home_team_id`), I want the `home_rolling_avg` to be equal 3. It shouldn't take into account the current row.

**Question:**

How do I calculate each team's goals expanding **average/mean**, based on previous values in `total_goals` and excluding the current row, and assign this mean value to the relevant column (depends on whether the team is playing at home or away)?

```
    total_goals  home_team_id  away_team_id  home_goals  away_goals  home_rolling_avg  away_rolling_avg
0             2          1277          1241           1           1               NaN               NaN
1             3          1245          1249           2           1               NaN               NaN
2             1          1242          1246           0           1               NaN               NaN
3             4          1261          1248           1           3               NaN               NaN
4             2          1259          1240           2           0               NaN               NaN
5             3          2981          1268           1           2               NaN               NaN
6             1          1244          1255           1           0               NaN               NaN
7             1          1254          1276           1           0               NaN               NaN
8             7          1247         12140           5           2               NaN               NaN
9             3          5681          1270           2           1               NaN               NaN
10            1          1249          5681           0           1               NaN               NaN
# in line 10 above, 'home_rolling_avg' should show 3 (3/1)
```

### Update:

a larger sample (n=100) can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/yUWjpEaa). Added due a request by the kind [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared) ([answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41671884/5013234)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# easy tracking of long column names
hw = ['home_team_id', 'away_team_id']

# I found it easier to melt myself with some numpy help
hw_vals = df[hw].values.ravel()  # flatten 2 columns
idx_rep = df.index.values.repeat(2)  # repeat index [0, 0, 1, 1, ...
tot_rep = df.total_goals.values.repeat(2)  # repeat totals [2, 2, 3, 3, ...

# This is the reshaped series of team ids with total_goals
s = pd.Series(tot_rep, [idx_rep, hw_vals])

# groupby with a combination of expanding().mean() and shift()
e = s.groupby(level=1).apply(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift()).dropna()

# style preference of mine to do assignments using index values
# and to get it done in one line
df.set_index(hw[0], append=1).assign(home_rolling_avg=e).reset_index(hw[0]) \
  .set_index(hw[1], append=1).assign(away_rolling_avg=e).reset_index(hw[1])
```

[image]

---

***Deeper Explanation***

- One of the main "tricks" of this question is to recognize the ids in two columns as a common id.  We could use [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), which I did.  But I found the syntax to be uglier than what I ended up doing.  And I know that numpy does it quicker anyway.

  - I have two columns of ids, I flatten it with [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html).  This will double the length.  In this example, length went from 10 to 20.
  - Then I create a new version of the existing index using [`repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html).  Every value in the index gets repeated.  Eg, `[1, 2]` becomes `[1, 1, 2, 2]`.  I'll use this in conjunction withe the ids themselves to create a multi-index
  - repeat the `total_goals` column analogous to above
  - create a pandas series with the values of `total_goals` and a multi-index consisting of the prior index as the first level, and the team ids as the second level.  The multi-index was specified by passing the list of arrays as the index parameter `[idx_rep, hw_vals]`
- Now that I have this series, I can group by the second level of the index `level=1` and do and `expanding().mean()`.

  - However, I needed to execute this as a lambda in order to lag or shift it one period.  The lag/shift was necessary to only account for the expanding mean up to but not including the current match.
- We could use join, or a number of other techniques to get the relevant information combined with the original data set.  However, this felt more natural to me.

  - By setting the to ***include*** the home team id, I can then [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to include a new column to a copy.  I like this approach because it allows me to chain commands.  So I do, by resetting the index and repeating the process for the away team.  The assignment works because the indices line up naturally.

---

***Alternative Approach***
Using `defaultdict` + `Counter` from `collections`
Very similar to Steven Rouch

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
c, d = Counter(), defaultdict(int)
home_avgpg = pd.Series(index=df.index)
away_avgpg = pd.Series(index=df.index)

for row in df.itertuples():
    h = row.home_team_id
    a = row.away_team_id
    t = row.total_goals
    if h in c:
        home_avgpg.set_value(i, d[h] / c[h])
    if a in c:
        away_avgpg.set_value(i, d[a] / c[a])
    d[h] += t
    d[a] += t
    c.update([h, a])
```

---

@StevenRauch's answer is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

I think this meets the problem statement.  It uses `itertuples` to iterate each row and compute a running average:

```
teams_rolling_goals = {}
home_rolling_avg = []
away_rolling_avg = []

for row in df.itertuples():
    # get previous goal and game counts
    home_goals = teams_rolling_goals.get(row.home_team_id, (0, 0.))
    away_goals = teams_rolling_goals.get(row.away_team_id, (0, 0.))

    # calc a rolling average
    home_avg = np.nan if home_goals[1] == 0 \
        else home_goals[0] / home_goals[1]
    away_avg = np.nan if away_goals[1] == 0 \
        else away_goals[0] / away_goals[1]

    # save the averages for the row
    home_rolling_avg.append(home_avg)
    away_rolling_avg.append(away_avg)

    # accum rolling goals/games count
    teams_rolling_goals[row.home_team_id] = (
        home_goals[0] + int(row.total_goals), home_goals[1] + 1)
    teams_rolling_goals[row.away_team_id] = (
        away_goals[0] + int(row.total_goals), away_goals[1] + 1)

    print(row.home_team_id, home_rolling_avg[-1],
          row.away_team_id, away_rolling_avg[-1])

# save the results
df['home_rolling_avg'] = home_rolling_avg
df['away_rolling_avg'] = away_rolling_avg
```

Sample data used:

```
data = np.array([
    ('week', 'total_goals', 'home_team_id', 'away_team_id', 'home_goals',
     'away_goals', 'home_rolling_avg', 'away_rolling_avg'),
    (0, 2, 1277, 1241, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan),
    (1, 3, 1245, 1249, 2, 1, np.nan, np.nan),
    (2, 1, 1242, 1246, 0, 1, np.nan, np.nan),
    (3, 4, 1261, 1248, 1, 3, np.nan, np.nan),
    (4, 2, 1259, 1240, 2, 0, np.nan, np.nan),
    (5, 3, 2981, 1268, 1, 2, np.nan, np.nan),
    (6, 1, 1244, 1255, 1, 0, np.nan, np.nan),
    (7, 1, 1254, 1276, 1, 0, np.nan, np.nan),
    (8, 7, 1247, 12140, 5, 2, np.nan, np.nan),
    (9, 3, 5681, 1270, 2, 1, np.nan, np.nan),
    (10, 1, 1249, 5681, 0, 1, np.nan, np.nan),
])

index = data[1:, 0]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:, 1:],
                  index=index,
                  columns=data[0, 1:])
```